# how to include and compile a library in a makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to build this hello world project that includes a library with both `.h` and `.cpp` files (and hence the library needs to be compiled too). The directory structure is

```
helloworld/lib/StanfordCPPLib/console.h
          /src/hello.h
          /src/hello.cpp
```

You can see the project code [here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106b//lectures/1-Functions/code/helloWorld//)

When I run `make` with the following makefile, i get an error that `console.h` (which is included by `hello.cpp`) cannot be found

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.

DEPS = hello.h
OBJ = hello.o

#console.h is in lib/StanfordCPPLib and it is included by hello.cpp
INC=-I../lib/StanfordCPPLib

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) 

hellomake: $(OBJ)
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(INC)
```

How to include the StanfordLibrary in this makefile so that it is both included and compiled.

(note, I'm aware the original sourcecode contains a QT creator file, however, I'm trying to build it using make)

Comment: Before you see the error message, you will see the command that gets executed to compile the program, a few lines above it. If you look at the actual command that's executed, you should be able to figure out the problem all by yourself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik wadr, if you downvoted because it's your opinion I "should be able to figure out the problem all by" myself, I don't think that's a legitimate reason for downvote

Comment: @Leahcim Well, you should show us at least the errors you are getting.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it says in the OP the errors I'm getting: `i get an error that console.h (which is included by hello.cpp) cannot be found` i.e. the console.h file in the Stanford library isn't found --note also that the Stanford library contains .cpp files so it needs to be compiled.

Comment: There is a contradiction in the makefile: is console.h in -I../lib/StanfordCPPLib or -I../lib/StanfordCPP/Lib ? Also, what directory is your makefile in?

Comment: @rationalcoder I fixed the contradiction (it was just a typo) in the OP. The makefile is in `/src/`, hence I do `../lib/StanfordCPPLib` to refer to the dir where console.h is.  You can see the project sourcecode here (which I had also linked to in the OP). http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106b//lectures/1-Functions/code/helloWorld//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your rule for building objs:

```
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

doesn't use your include path in $(INC)

Another problem is that you are matching on the wrong file extension. e.g. `%.c` should be `%.cpp`.

You also have some extra redundant junk in there, so I suggest you update your makefile like this to get the idea:

```
CC=gcc

DEPS = hello.h
OBJ = hello.o
INC=-I. -I../lib/StanfordCPPLib

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(INC) -c $<

hellomake: $(OBJ)
    g++ -o $@ $^
```

This builds fine in my little mock setup.
Remember that it is actually necessary for you to use g++ under `hellomake:` for everything to link properly.

Comment: this answer takes me one step farther but does not properly link in all the library code. It gives me an error `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "startupMain(int, char**)", referenced from: _main in hello.o` . That function `startupMain` is declared in several files in the Stanford library that are included in `console.h` of the StanfordCPPLibrary (see link to source code in OP). So do you see how your solution might not be properly linking in those libraries? if so, please amend if you have time.

Comment: @Leahcim I could have sworn I already put a comment here, but YES I see how this makefile isn't linking in the libraries. This was just an example to fix the specific problem that you mentioned in the OP. All this makefile does is compile hello.cpp with the includes setup properly. If you want to build and link the libraries, you will need to create a target for the library and, under it, ``cd`` into the Stanford library directory and compile the library. Once you have a library, you will need to tell the compiler, under your hellomake target, where to find the library (-L) and link to it (-l)

Comment: @Leahcim Actually, it looks like the project file they gave you is an APP that is expecting your code to have the main function. i.e NOT a library. In any case, that pro file is quite complicated and would be rough to completely replicate for someone just starting out with makefiles. You will need to compile all the files in in the Stanford directories and add ``../libStanfordCPPLib/*.o`` (plus all the other directories) to your LIB and ``../libStanfordCPPLib/*.h`` (plus all the other directories) to your INC, then link to the libraries that the Stanford code uses for your platform.